# Objects not instantiating after touch

Tags: c#, instantiation, unity-game-engine

I've been digging around and trying to find the answer to this question but found nothing. I'm trying to create a simple clicker game but got stuck at the very start... which is not very good. What I'm trying to do is after a touch give the player money (currently just adding +1$) and spawning in a text object saying "+1$". Seems like the object does not appear. I also made an "animation" which I'm not sure if it's well made. Both classes:

```
public class TapTextMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private int frameCount = 0;
private float temp;
public int modifier = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (frameCount < 40) {
        temp = this.transform.position.y + 1F * modifier;

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, temp, this.transform.position.z);
    } else if (frameCount < 50) {
        temp = this.transform.position.y + 0.5F * modifier;

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, temp, this.transform.position.z);
    } else if (frameCount < 55) {
        temp = this.transform.position.y + 0.3F * modifier;

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, temp, this.transform.position.z);
    } else if (frameCount < 60) {
        temp = this.transform.position.y + 0.15F * modifier;

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, temp, this.transform.position.z);
    } else {
        Object.Destroy (this);
    }
    frameCount++;
}
}
```

And:

```
public class MoneyTap : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject money;
private Text moneyText;
public long moneyAmount = 0;
public GameObject tapText;
private Vector2 tempPos;
private Vector3 fullPos;

void Start () {
    moneyText = money.GetComponent<Text> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    moneyText.text = moneyAmount + "$";

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

            tempPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            fullPos = new Vector3 (tempPos.x, tempPos.y, 0);


            RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);
            if (hitInfo) {
                moneyAmount++;;
                Instantiate(tapText, fullPos, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am a bit new to Unity so every bit of help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just an advice, don't create animations in **Update** as it affects performance, as these changes are performed once per frame render

Comment: Is there an alternative? Why not do it? I want to change it's position every frame for a second or two, then delete it. Each frame the object will go up by a # of disctance, why would I now want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To instantiate the object use function:

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(tapText, fullPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Also don't create animation in Update, as this causes problems and affect performance.

There could be a problem in your **TapTextMovement** class, when you instantiate object, it copies all it's scripts, so you should reset the *frameCount*, *modifier* on **Start**, or change your script entirely.

Because if you copy an existing object in the scene it should save its script values, try creating a prefab and instantiating from it.

Now it seems to remove your object just after instantiating it as **frameCount** is already over 60.

Check if that works.

Comment: I didn't even think my script through, now that I realise it. The text object that I'm trying to copy is long gone, it deleted itself. Instantiating a prefab would most likely fix my problem. Thanks!